# Visual studio solution with multiple projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am relatively new to the corporate world and hence just started to use Visual Studio 2019. I have been given the task of testing a new software on some C++ project built using MSVC compiler. And I have been asked to test it on a solution containing multiple projects. I know that a single solution of visual studio can contain multiple projects. I have trying to find such a solution but so far I have no luck in finding such a project. Can anyone please tell me if there is any Microsoft visual studio open source solution with multiple projects written in C++?

Comment: Why not create one yourself? Start by creating a simple hello-world project. Then you can create a new project in the solution (IIRC by right-clicking on the solution and selecting new project or something similar). Now you have a single solution with two projects. Now try to create a few more different projects, like for example a static and a dynamic library, and make the initial "hello world" type application projects depend on those libraries. And since it's your own solution and projects, you can scrap it and start over if there's something wrong.

Comment: I tried creating one but they mentioned that it was a trivial project. They need some complex project which could test the software rigorously. That is the reason I am searching for one.